# How to shuffle array with yq

Tags: arrays, sorting, unix, yaml, yq

There is documentation explaining how to sort an array using yq https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/sort

But it'd like to shuffle (random sorting)

Given an example

- a: banana
- a: cat
- a: apple

i'd like to sort it randomly yq 'sort_by(RANDOM)' sample.yml

Any ideas?

I'd tried the examples in the official documentation
https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/sort

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to do here? i.e. a sample YAML list and what shuffling you want to perform?

Comment: In the context of a [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm, which yq mostly tries to adhere to, the design choices focus on pure functions and their predictable compositions. Randomness as a concept must lie outside these principles. What you could do is importing a random seed value from the calling environment, and base your ordering on that. From purely within yq, you could alternatively fall back on pseudo-random values such as the current time to obtain such a seed value.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally, yq does not provide a shuffle command.

---

A workaround, until [your github issue](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1503) is being worked on, could by to use the bash build-in [`shuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf):

1. Export Bash variable with `yq`'s output piped to `shuf`
2. Use `yq`'s [`env`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators) to insert the bash variable into the desired place

```bash
export shuffled=$(yq e '.MyData' input | shuf)
yq e '.MyData |= env(shuffled)' input
```

Will output a pesuedo random order of the `MyData` array